# Golang/mgo: How can I ask MongoDB to use current time in a field?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have this struct that matches the types of a MongoDB collection I'm using:

```
type AppInstance struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId "_id,omitempty"
    Url string
    Priority int
    LastSeen string
}
```

I want the LastSeen field to hold the time of the last interaction with that particular app.  So, the app registers itself setting current time (as a string).

What I would like is Mongo to dynamically set its own current time into that field when it inserts, just like MySQL's NOW() function would do.

I have this helper function:

```
func mongoNow() bson.JavaScript {
    return bson.JavaScript{Code: 
         "return (new Date()).ISODate('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');"}
}
```

And I tried this:

```
c := mongoSession.DB("myapp").C("instances")
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
err := c.Insert(
   struct{Id, Serial, Priority, Url, LastSeen interface{}}{ 
      Id: bson.NewObjectId(), 
      Url: getInformedHost() + ":" + getRunningPortString(), 
      Priority: rand.Int(), 
      LastSeen: mongoNow() }
)
checkError(err, "Could not register on MongoDB server.", 3)
```

the LastSeen field gets stored as a script instead of evaluated:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 502d6f984eaead30a134fa10
)
[id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 502d6f98aa443e0ffd000001
)
[priority] => 1694546828
[url] => 127.0.0.1:8080
[lastseen] => MongoCode Object (
    [code] => (new Date()).ISODate('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
    [scope] => Array (
    )
)
```

So, I think there are to questions:

First, how can I insert the current time?

Second, how can I get some javascript evaluated instead of inserted?

The answer to the second one could be enough to answer the first one, but it might as well not be.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Don't store time as string. mgo supports [time.Time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) which is like a `Date` object in Javascript:

```
type Event struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId "_id,omitempty"
    Which string
    Date  time.Time
}
```

Insert an event that happened now:

```
e := Event{
    Which: "first event",
    Date: time.Now(),
}
c.Insert(e)
```

Comment: Great!  How could I query for instances that did not report for the last hour?  Can I use `>`?

Comment: I'm already storing `time.Time` as you suggested, but I'm still curious about evaluating some javascript, and also about finding out Mongo's current time.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli That should work: `db.C("events").Find(bson.M{"date": bson.M{"$gt": time.Now().Add(-time.Hour)}})`

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli About evaluating Javascript with mgo, better open a new question because I'm not sure.

Comment: @Zippoxer I think you meant `$lt`

Comment: Thanks +Zippoxer, I just did open a new question as you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008910/golang-mgo-how-can-i-ask-mongodb-to-evaluate-some-javascript-in-order-to-obtain

Comment: @Tom Yeah. I forgot to refer to http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

Comment: to load you data you can simply decode queried data into you struct with bson tags.

Answer (score 5):

In Mongo 2.6 you can do it natively with [$currentDate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate) operator.

```
db.users.update( { _id: 1 }, {
   $currentDate: {
     lastModified: true,
     lastModifiedTS: { $type: "timestamp" }
   },
   $set: { status: "D" }
})
```