# Go and Mongodb: Parameters to eval in mgo (mongodb driver)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Suppose that I have an an array of strings and a map (that I can eventually serialize to JSON), how can I call a javascript function function store in db.system.js that accepts an array and a dictionary?

```
db.Run(bson.M{"eval": "myStoredFunction(<MY ARRAY>, <MY DICTIONARY>);"})
```

Comment: Is your question how to make the call to a stored function, or how to pass the data to the function when issuing db.Run?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008910/golang-mgo-how-can-i-ask-mongodb-to-evaluate-some-javascript-in-order-to-obtain and also http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval