# execute mongodb functions from mgo golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Is it possible to use mgo driver to execute mongodb functions during an update or insert while using a struct object?

```
err := db.C(collectionName).UpdateId(eventID, Event{
    Name: eventName,
    Club: getClubName(clubID), //how to call mongodb getClubName function?
})
```

I have a mongodb function that returns a club name when given a club id. The following executes OK in the mongodb shell.

```
db.loadServerScripts();
db.Event.update({"_id" : "30fc..."}, {"name": "foo_bar" , "clubName": getClubName("4df32...")});
```

I can execute an additional database lookup to get the club name, but would prefer this to be atomic if possible.

Comment: @Speedy, did you ever figure this out? Despite Markus's dismissive comment, this is useful. The [MongoDB documentation recommends using a similar function to implement an auto-increment field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), for example.

Comment: @NathanSmith, I don't think mgo supports these types of queries which is a shame. Ended up replacing MongoDB with [Bolt](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt). Its much better as an embedded transactional database. Used disk space is 42 times smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008910/how-can-i-ask-mongodb-to-evaluate-some-javascript-in-order-to-obtain-value-for-a), there is no way to evaluate JavaScript during an insert. I think it's a safe assumption that the same goes for updates, upserts, etc.

You can achieve this in two calls by using mgo's db.Run() method:

```
db.Run(bson.M{"eval": fmt.Sprintf("getClubName(%s);", clubID)}, &resp)
```

And then using the result in your update statement.

Unfortunately, there is no way to make things atomic using this technique. If atomicity is a requirement, I would recommend keeping all the business logic in your application and using a local or database-based locking mechanism.