# How to insert javascritpt function in Mongodb using Go driver or Golang

Tags: javascript, mongodb, go

I saw the below code in mongodb official site, to insert a Javascript function in mongodb.

```
db.system.js.save(
   {
     _id: "echoFunction",
     value : function(x) { return x; }
   }
)
```

link is:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

I tried the procedures in mongoShell and it is working good.
Now, I want to store javascript function in to mongodb using golang.

I saw the below structure  in [gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson package](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson).

```
// JavaScript is a type that holds JavaScript code. If Scope is non-nil, it
// will be marshaled as a mapping from identifiers to values that may be
// used when evaluating the provided Code.
type JavaScript struct {
    Code  string
    Scope interface{}
}
```

Does it relates to what I expected?
Please share your Knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how First create a function that will return `bson.JavaScript` struct :

```
func mongoNow() bson.JavaScript {

    return bson.JavaScript{
      // place your function in here in string
      Code: "(new Date()).ISODate('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')"
    }
}
```

And insert to your collections :

```
c := mongoSession.DB("YourDB").C("YourCollection")
err := c.Insert(
   struct{LastSeen interface{}}
      {  
         LastSeen: mongoNow() 
      }
)
```

Please do not forget to insert your appropriate `import` package.

Comment: Thank you @GujaratSantana, i can able to store the function in system.js collection. How can I execute the js  form golang

Comment: @hariprasad see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008910/how-can-i-ask-mongodb-to-evaluate-some-javascript-in-order-to-obtain-value-for-a

Comment: Im not sure if it was ever valid, but `bson.javaScript` ain't a thing anymore. `primitive.JavaScript("console.log("Your script here")` is the way now