# query by date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm able to insert an entry into MongoDB using the golang driver  `gopkg.in/mgo.vs` and `gopkg.in/mgo.vs/bson` but I'm not able to pull it out.  In the mongo shell, if I do

```
db.Items.find({ date : 1428762411980 })
```

it shows me the entry that I just inserted with the Go code. However, if I try to do the following to fetch it in Go, it's telling me that the record isn't found

```
    func fetch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
         var result SomeStruct
         date := r.FormValue("date")
         err := Items.Find(bson.M{"date":date}).One(&result)
         ...code omitted...

    }

   func Items() *mgo.Collection {
       return DB().C("Items")
    }

   func DB() *mgo.Database {
      return DBSession().DB("mydb")
    }
```

One thing I noticed was that, in the shell, the date is stored as a `NumberLong`

```
 "date" : NumberLong("1428762411980")
```

I'm wondering if I have to do something with the date value that I receive from the form in the `fetch` function before using it to query the database?

Update

Before saving the data to the db, it comes in as a json string like this

```
"date":1428762411980
```

I then decode it into a struct

```
type blah struct{
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Date int64 `json:"date" bson: "date"`
```

And it gets saved like this (as shown in the shell)

```
 "date" : NumberLong("1428762411980")
```

Comment: I think In your documents date save in `unix time stamp`  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996693/golang-mgo-how-can-i-ask-mongodb-to-use-current-time-in-a-field

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully get your point. Before saving the record, I decode it to a field like this `Date int64 `json:"date" bson: "date"`` What would you recommend I do?

Comment: Should I create another field on the struct with a different type and convert the unix time stamp to another type to use for storage. If so, what and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.FormValue` returns a string, but you need an int64. Use [strconv.ParseInt](http://godoc.org/strconv#ParseInt). Then your query should work.

```
date, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("date"), 10, 64)
// handle err
err = Items.Find(bson.M{"date":date}).One(&result)
```